# How to make a multi dimensional array in react native in this format data: [[],[],[]]?

Tags: arrays, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react-native-table-component in my project and the format of the accepted array data should be like this:

```
tableData: [
   ['1', '2', '3',],
   ['a', 'b', 'c',],
   ['1', '2', '3',],
]
```

I tried to push and map. But I don't know why I couldn't format the array in that way.

I tried this code:

```
this.state.tableData.push('1');
this.state.tableData.push('2');
this.state.tableData.push('3');
```

but it seems the data format in the array is something like this:

```
tableData: [1,2,3]
```

The data will be fetch from my firebase database looks like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('Budgets/id/Expenses').once("value", function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            this.state.tableData.push(data.val().name);
            this.state.tableData.push(data.val().amount);
            this.state.tableData.push(data.val().frequency);           
          })
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Any idea or suggestion to come up with that array format?

SOLUTION:

```
let roww = [];
let that = this;
    firebase.database().ref('Budgets/id/Expenses').once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        roww.push([data.val().name,data.val().amount,data.val().frequency]); 
        that.setState({tableData: roww});
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what's the problem..if the accepted format is a bidimenstional array, well.. build it.

```
let firstRow = [1,2,3]
this.state.tableData = [firstRow]
```

Push action

```
this.state.tableData[0].push(1)
```

Few more details would helps

**EDIT:**
try this (please note `this.state.tableData` have to be initialized)

```
          snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            this.state.tableData.push([data.val().name,data.val().amount,data.val().frequency]);           
          })
```

Comment: I added few more details in the question.

Comment: do your rows are composed by triples [name,amount,frequency]?

Comment: yes. tableData: [ [name,amount,frequency], [name,amount,frequency] ] which all the data will be fetch from the database depending how many expenses available.

Comment: I edited my post, try to replace your forEach body with mine

Comment: I tried it and it works. Just did few edits. thanks.

Comment: seeing your solution, you totally have to move  `setState()` action out of the forEach

Answer (score 0):

This a working example. I think it will help to solve your problem. Check the componentDidmount()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';

export default class ExampleOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['Head', 'Head2', 'Head3', 'Head4'],
      tableData: [
        ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['1', '2', '3', '456\n789'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){

var myarray=new Array(3)
var k= 1
var j= 2
var l= 9
for (var i=0; i <3; i++)
    myarray[i]=[j,k,l]

  this.setState({tableData:myarray})

  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6 }
})
```

You can test here also [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@masukhelal/multidimenstional-array)